# Overriding eval globals with __getattr__ problems

Tags: python, metaprogramming, getattr

I'm trying to override globals so that any attribute name 
that doesn't exists returns itself(the name string).
The reason for this is to use it in eval to do some quick/hacky parsing of a c initilizer list, (and just because of course).
My Code:

```
class EvalGlobalsDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if hasattr(self, name):
            return super(EvalGlobalsDict, self).__getattr__(name) 
        else:
            return name


eval_globals = EvalGlobalsDict(globals())
```

Whenever I try to eval a non existent name it gives me a NameError

```
eval("aaa",eval_globals)
```

And if I try to directly call

```
eval("globals().__getattr__("dir")",eval_globals)
eval("globals().__getattr__("dir")",eval_globals)
```

I only get back the attr name string even for valid attributtes.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The answer given by AKX is correct, but FYI `__getattr__` only gets called if regular attribute lookup fails, so you don't need the `if` / `else` -- just `return name` would do it (if it was actually attribute access you wanted to modify).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're subclassing a dict, you'll want to override `__getitem__` (the indexing accessor).

```
class EvalGlobalsDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return self.get(name, name)

foo = 1337
eval_globals = EvalGlobalsDict(globals())
print repr(eval("aaa", eval_globals))
print repr(eval("foo", eval_globals))
```

prints

```
> 'aaa'
> 1337
```